# Does "X and Y are different" only mean "X is different from Y"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, coordination

If someone says "X and Y are different.", does it only mean "X is different from Y."? Is there any chance in which it means "X is identical to Y but both are different from others."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that it's ambiguous.  It could mean either of the following:

> 1. X and Y are different **from each other**.　　*(joint interpretation)*
> 2. X and Y are different **from Z**.　　　　 *(distributive interpretation)*

In the joint interpretation you're considering X and Y as a single unit.

In the distributive interpretation, you're considering X and Y individually, so the second meaning can be rephrased as follows:

> 3. X is different **from Z**, and Y is different **from Z**.

This is a little different from what you said in your question – there is no implication that X and Y are identical.  They could be the same, or they could be different.  But you're right that it's ambiguous whether X and Y are different from each other or from something else.